# In how many ways ways can the coach make substitutions in a soccer match?

Tags: combinatorics

[image: question]

My solution: 
Coach can pick any one of the 11 subs and then place the sub in any one of the 11 places so that's (11)(11) ways

Then coach can pick any of the 10 remaining subs and place them again in 11 places in (10)(11) ways

Finally coach can pick any of the 9 remaining subs and place them in any of the 11 places 9(11) ways

Therefore total is (11)(11)× (10)(11)×(9)(11) +1 way for no subs = 1317691

Divided by 1000 the remaining amt is 691

Comment: You've counted the possibilities for three substitutions or none, but there could also be one or two.

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot to do that

Comment: I'm guessing for two substitutions it would be (11)(11)×(10)(11) and for one is (11)(11) . And after adding together and dividing I got 122